# Given an image how to find height of an object?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, 3d-object-detection

If I have an image of apple then how can I find the height of an apple using Deep learning?

The photo of an apple is taken from the top view and I want to detect the height of that apple. How to do it?

Are there any papers regarding this?

I have searched a lot but the solution were only giving me length and breadth but not height. So how to determine height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the apple next to a penny and capture a top level view. Then by using the known ground truth (since you know dimensions of penny), you can estimate the distance to the ground and distance to the top of the apple. After that you should be able to infer the height of the apple.

If you know the dimensions of the plate with certainty then yes.

Comment: Let say the user clicks the photo of the fruit from the camera and we have to predict the height then instead of penny can we use plate as a ground truth if the apple is in the plate ?